# Virtualenv error, unable to create process

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

I recently cleaned up my system variables and I think I might have mixed something up. I have two versions of Python installed: 3.4 and 3.6.2. One is situated in C:/Python3.4 and the other one in AppData folder. I wanted to use Python 3.6.2 and virtualenv again to create another working environment, but I get the following error:

```
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"'
```

If I try using pip, everything works fine and virtualenv is installed.

Answer (score 2):

Happenned to me today.

I solved it by uninstalling python and installing Python x86 in **C:\Python\Python37_32** FOR ALL USERS

Then I've added **C:\Python\Python37_32** and **C:\Python\Python37_32\Scripts** to the PATH env variable.

Then using cmd I installed virtualenv with `pip install virtualenv`.

After that virtualenv worked like a charm.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I tried almost all measures I can search on Google. But I solved this issue by re-install certifi `pip install certifi`